# Move file based on condition

Tags: shell-script, mv

Can anyone help me finding solution to my requirement.

the requirement is I have to write a shell script which will scan a directory and read each file coming to it and will search for a string starts with (like "AB00732614") It will search for all files which contains AB* then it will move the file to another directory.

Comment: Why not just `mv dir1/AB* dir2`?

Comment: Is the string part of the filename or part of the contents of the file?

Comment: AB is string which is inside many files.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the string `AB`-etc. is part of the *contents* of the files to be moved:

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -exec grep -qE 'AB[0-9]{8}' {} \; -exec mv -i {} /path/to/destination/ \;
```

This uses `find` to find all regular files under `/path/to/dir`.  For each file, `grep` will look whether it contains anything matching the extended regular expression `AB[0-9]{8}` (the string `AB` followed by exactly eight digits).  If it does, the file is moved to the directory `/path/to/destination/`.

If another file with the same name as the file being moved is already in the destination directory, you will have to confirm that you would like to overwrite that file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
find . -type f -iname 'AB*' -exec mv -t ./another_directory/ {} \+
```

It is very well explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5607677

Comment: Note that it's GNU specific and will also move files whose name starts with `ab` or `Ab` or `aB` (and will only move _regular_ files, not the other types of files like _directory_, _symlink_, _device_, _fifo_...)

Comment: Thanks Mqtoto but it is not working..